# TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object[using express router] --

Tags: node.js, express, lambda, typeerror, nodejs-server

The app, I am building with nodeJS expressJS is for connecting to a sqlserver database and retrieving data. Am trying to make the code as modular and
reusable as posssible. So different files for routing and controller. The error I am now facing is-

```
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
```

For ease of understanding of the imports, my project structure is as such:

```
controller
    |-- controller.js
db
    |-- db.js
query
    |-- queries.json
routes
    |-- route.js
package.json
server.js
```

My main server.js file is

```
const express = require('express')

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const router=require('./routes/route');
const app = express()

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(morgan('dev'));

const port = 3200

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port , (err) => {
  if(err)
  {
    console.log('Unable to start the server!');
  }
  else
    console.log('NodeExpress Data API started running on : ' + port);
})
```

the controller file is

```
const express=require('express')

const { sql, poolPromise } = require('../db/db')
const fs = require('fs');


class MainController
{
    async getAllData(req, resp)
    {
        try 
        {
            const pool = await poolPromise
            const result = await pool.request()
            .query("select * from players");
            resp.json(result.recordset)
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            resp.status(500)
            resp.send(error.message)
        }
    }

}

const controller=new MainController();
module.exports=controller;
```

and the route file is

```
const express =  require('express');
const controller = require('../controller/controller')

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/getAllData', controller.getAllData);
```

So when I insert this line
app.use('api/', router) in the server.js to wire all the modules together and make calls to api endpoint to get all data, I am getting that error mentioned.

What is it about, can anyone explain me in simple terms? Is the error being thrown from the controller file, since I am initializing a new instance of the controller type? Which line from which file is throwing this error? What is the code correction needed to remove this error?

Comment: did you export your router module before require on server.js ? Also bodyParser is deprecated for the new express releases and you can use app.use(express.json(...))

Comment: hi @AbhikChakraborty I have rectified the error. and added new code too for querying and fetching records from the db. It is giving me error. See edited portion on original post for the error and new code. Thanks for info on body-parser. Looks like express.json() will suffice.

Comment: I guess you are still missing the following on the router file 
`module.exports = router;`

In addition your controllers are functions of a class and you may use in the router something like 

router.get("/getAllData",
    (...args) => controller.getAllData(...args)
);

And make sure on your server file you add app.use(router) after the import in there before app.lisiten

Answer (score 1):

under route.js change to `router.get('/getAllData', controller.getAllData());` you have passed `controller.getAllData` as a handler function instead of `controller.getAllData()` as per the type of method you have used in class. hope this solves the error.

Comment: yes, it does @nabhagmotivaras. mistake I overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

Try out one of these:

1- if your are using express and doing

```
const router = express.Router();
```

make sure to

```
module.exports = router ;
```

at the end of your page

2- If your are using express above 2.x, you have to declare app.router like below code. Please try to replace your code

```
app.use('/', routes);
```

with

```
app.use(app.router);
routes.initialize(app);
```